# React Native: Update ListView Row when props changes

Tags: react-native, react-native-listview, shoutem

I do have a ListView component with a `renderRow()` function. My custom `ListBountiesView` component which renders a ListView Row also takes a prop called `cr` and displays some content in each row depending on the value of `cr`.

The problem is that when `this.props.customerRelationship` changes its value, the ListView rows do not get updated.

I am doing it with: `this.props.customerRelationship.points += responseJson.points;`

I guess that `ListView` only updates when the `data` attribute changes, but how can I move props to my renderRow component so that they also update the ListView?

**SuperScreen.js**

```
renderRow(bounty) {
  const { customerRelationship } = this.props;
  return (
    <ListBountiesView
      key={bounty.id}
      bounty={bounty}
      cr={customerRelationship}
      onPress={this.openDetailsScreen}
    />
  );
}

render() {
    const { bounties } = this.props;

    return (
      <ListView
          data={bounties}
          renderRow={this.renderRow}
          loading={loading}
      />
    )
```

Comment: You're not updating your `dataSource` anywhere that's why it doesn't change. As other's have suggested, you need to use other lifecycle events to capture the change. Alternatively you could look into using `FlatList` which doesn't require you to setup a `dataSource` object and just takes an array - that way it is automatically updated when your props change.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The ListView refreshes the data source when the `data` prop gets a new reference:

```
 componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.data !== this.props.data) {
      this.setState({ dataSource: this.listDataSource.clone(nextProps.data) });
    }

    if (nextProps.loading !== this.props.loading) {
      this.setLoading(nextProps.loading);
    }
  }
```

Similarly, React Native's ListView refreshes when its data source changes. This was discussed on their GitHub and in many other threads. The generally accepted workaround is to create a new data array. In your case, do it in `componentWillReceiveProps` whenever `customerRelationship` changes.

Comment: `cloneWithRows`

Answer (score 0):

Move your `customerRelationship` to `bounty` object. Each `bounty` should have this property, then check it's value changed in the `rowHasChanged`. Other way is to check  `customerRelationship` in `componentWillReceiveProps` function, if it's value changed clone `bounties` so all of it's child have new object reference.